# Cutting down a probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume you have probability measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ with no mass in $0$, formal $\mu(\left\{0\right\})=0$.

**Problem 1**: Which conditions has $\mu$ to satisfy such that $\frac{1}{x^2}\mu(dx)$ is again a probability measure?

Obviously the problem here is $lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^2}=\infty$ and our measure $\mu$ has to compensate the growth towards $0$.

**My first attempt**

First step was to approximate $\frac{1}{x^2}$ trough simple functions $\phi_n$ and analyse how my measure $\mu$ has to behave:

Take the partition $\pi_n:=\left\{0,\frac{1}{n},...,\right\}$ of $[0,1]$ and take the simple function
$\phi_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n^2}{i^2}\mathbb{1}_{[\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}]}(x)$
if we compute the integral from $\phi_n$ w.r.t. to $\mu$ we get:

$\int_{[0,1]}\phi_n(x)\mu(dx)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n^2}{i^2}\mu([\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}])$

and the above sum has to converge to $1$ s.t. $\frac{1}{x^2}\mu(dx)$ is a probability measure.

My first try was to assume that $\mu$ has to satisfy something like $\mu([\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}])=\frac{6}{(n\pi)^2}$. Then the sum above would converge to $1$ because of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. This attempts fails because we need $\mu$ to be probability measure.

**Problem 2** Assume we solved Problem 1 and take another probability measure $\psi$ on $[0,1]$ where $\frac{1}{x^2}\psi(dx)$ is measure but not necessary a prob. measure and as before $\psi(\left\{0\right\})=0$.

I want to "cut" $\psi$ with a sequence of increasing subsets $I_N$ of $[0,1]$ such that I can reproduce a measure $\mu$ as in problem 1. For example one could think of a cut like:

$\mu_N:= \psi(\cdot\cap I_N)$ and define the probability measure $\bar{\mu}_N(\cdot)=\frac{\mu_N(\cdot)}{\mu_N([0,1])}$

Of course the cut has to be much more involved, because we have to consider the constraints in problem 1.

It is possible that this constructions fails for some examples, any ideas and suggestions would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: For one thing, $x\mapsto 1/x^2$ needs to be measurable. It might help to consider the problem then for Borel measures only

Comment: @jakobdt I want know, if it is possible to construct from a general prob. measure $\psi$ on $[0,1]$ another prob. measure $\mu_{\psi}$ s.t. $\frac{1}{x^2}\mu_{\psi}(dx)$ is a prob. measure.

Comment: Taking $\mu_\psi(dx)=x^2dx$ does the trick but maybe this is cheating? I assume you want some connection between $\mu_\psi$ and $\psi$? Maybe you want to look at $\sigma$-finiteness. Given a $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ you can construct a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ which is equivalent to $\nu$ (i.e. they have the same null-sets). Look up $\sigma$-finite measures on Wikipedia to find this construction.

Comment: Yes, in some sense the connection is, that if we increase the sets $I_N$ that $\mu_{\psi}$ is in some sense the "normalised" measure $\psi$.

Comment: Somehow I overlooked the fact that $\psi$ is a probability measure. Then you can just take $\mu_\psi(dx)=x^2\psi(dx)$, resulting in $\tfrac{1}{x^2}\mu_\psi(dx)=\psi(dx)$.

Comment: I think that doesn't work, because if we take $\psi=\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, which is then a prob. measure, $\mu_{\psi}$ isn't. Just because $\mu_{psi}([0,1])=\int_{[0,1]}x^2\lambda(dx)=\frac{1}{3}$. But maybe this gives already hint, that problem 1 is not solveable, because we can't rescale a prob. measure in this way and still have a prob. measure. So we have to assume either $\mu$ or $\frac{1}{x^2}\mu(dx)$ is a prob. measure.